# Parallel studio not working with Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild, intel-parallel-studio

I am trying to run a nightly build on TFS 2018. One of the projects in my solution uses Intel C++ compiler. I have installed Parallel Studio XE 2015 update 5 composer edition and I have integrated it with the Visual Studio 2013 on the virtual machine.

During the execution I am getting the error:

> [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\Intel C++ Compiler XE 15.0\Toolset.targets(145,5): Error MSB8001: "MSG010" is an invalid value for the "Code" parameter.**

I tried to do some research online but I did not find any solution for my problem.
Can anyone who has faced a similar kind of issue help me with this?

Comment: What's the result if you build that project locally using msbuild command-line like `msbuild xx.vccxproj /t:build` ? Can it work?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT:When I build it locally using msbuild, it is still failing.